# Unable to invoke time critical function in ++ using timeGetTime() in VC++

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++

I want to send data through socket. I want my send code to be run automatically after every 10ms, so I used a logic using timeGetTime(). But it is not getting invoked, please help me. The program runs upto now time printing code but it is not entering the if condition!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<winsock2.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<time.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"winmm.lib") 

#define BUFF_SIZE 10485760

int sock_fd = 0;
char *a;
int nread = 0;
int c = 0;
int k = 0;
int nCount  = 0;

int main()
{ 
int ret=0, j=0;
a = (char*)calloc(BUFF_SIZE, sizeof(char));
WSAData version;        //We need to check the version.
WORD mkword=MAKEWORD(2,2);
int what=WSAStartup(mkword,&version);
if(what!=0)
{
  std::cout<<"This version is not supported! - \n"<<WSAGetLastError()<<std::endl;
}
else
{
  std::cout<<"Initialised.\n"<<std::endl;
}

sock_fd =socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
if(sock_fd==INVALID_SOCKET)
{
  std::cout<<"Creating socket fail\n";
}
else
{
  std::cout<<"It was okay to create the socket\n";
}
 //Socket address information
 sockaddr_in addr;
 addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
 addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("10.0.0.51");
 addr.sin_port=htons(5001);

 int conn=connect(sock_fd,(SOCKADDR*)&addr,sizeof(addr));
 if(conn==SOCKET_ERROR){
        std::cout<<"Error - when connecting "<<WSAGetLastError()<<std::endl;
    }
else
{
        std::cout<<"socket connect succesfully";
}
FILE*fp = fopen("binary.bin","wb+");
printf("\n File opened successfully through fopen()\n");
       //filling our dynamic memory pointed by a with some dynamic data
for(k=0;k<BUFF_SIZE;k++)
{
  a[k]=k;
}

 /* writing in file*/
 if (( c = fwrite(a, 1, BUFF_SIZE, fp)) != BUFF_SIZE)
  {
    printf ("\n Error : file write failure");
_getch();
    return 1;
  }
  printf("\n write bytes=%d\n",c);

  /* First read file in chunks of 10 bytes */
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
  int    nread = fread(a, 1, BUFF_SIZE,fp);
  printf(" read Bytes  %d \n", nread);

  unsigned int last_call_time = timeGetTime();
  printf("last call time %d\n", last_call_time);

  while(true)
  {
    unsigned int now_time = timeGetTime();
    printf("now time %d\n", now_time);
    if(now_time > (last_call_time + 10))
    {
      //call_time_critical_function();
     printf("performing time critical logic\n");
     for(j=0;j<BUFF_SIZE;j++){
     ret = send(sock_fd, a, 1,0) ;
     printf("ret %d\n", ret);
     last_call_time = timeGetTime();//last time is re initialized
        }
    }
getch();
return 0;      
}
}
```

**Debugging output:**
Initialised.

It was okay to create the socket

Error - when connecting 10060

File opened successfully through fopen

write bytes = 10

read bytes =10

last call time 4179968

now time 4179968

Comment: It would be much more useful to include the debug output as text.

Comment: Why you're sending that buffer of `nread` bytes `BUFF_SIZE` times is probably wrong, but that has nothing to do with your 10060 error, which means connection-timed-out. Apart from reporting said-error, you ignore it and march on regardless trying to send data over an unbound socket.

Comment: First of all, if is just a conditional check and it is not a loop Jeevan..! Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: A little indenting and error checking goes a long way.  `File opened successfully` is rather optimistic since you don't actually check.

Comment: Hi @WhozCraig Okay I replaced nread to 1. Sorry, I forgot to inform I don't have hardware with me right now, but put that connection part aside and can you please tell me if that time critical part is correct?

Comment: Hi @RetiredNinja oops wait I will check it and I will come back. I am so in confusion :(.

Comment: Using a loop like that should be fine.  You could easily test that outside the current code by replacing your code with a sleep or something.  Keep in mind that `send` can block, so although you may send again 10ms after send has returned the interval may not be 10ms.  You should also know that without `timeBeginPeriod(1)` the default precision of `timeGetTime` may be 5ms or more.

Answer (score 2):

Print time and check.

Edit:

Move return outside while loop. Also move getch() outside the while loop.

Comment: @RetiredNinja:  This is the answer!  The original code aborts the `while(true)` loop after the first iteration!